Upload files on the blockchain
I'd like to upload arbitrary files on the blockchain, so that they can't get deleted nor taken down, is there a known way?

There was no way, so I've written the Ethereum Virtual Machine File System.
To upload a file like nice_picture.jpg one can just type
evmfs \
  publish \
    "nice_picture.jpg"

To know the URI at which the file has been published or it will be published one can type:
evmfs \
  -m \
    "simulate" \
  publish \
    "nice_picture.jpg"

Giving the command without option, the resulting link will have the following form:
evmfs://<default_network_chain_id>/<default_file_system_deployment>/<your_address>/<sha256_checksum_of_nice_picture.jpg>

To retrieve the file back just type:
evmfs \
  get \
  "evmfs://your_file_address"

If the file has been published without options you can just give as input URI evmfs://<sha256_checksum_of_your_file>.

As a workaround, you can upload a file to ipfs and save the link on the blockchain

That's absolutely not a workaround, files served through the IPFS are not stored on the blockchain and they do not have any guarantee to stay online if the uploader goes offline.

Also IPFS developers foresee to implement blacklisting, aka censorship, anytime soon.

Thank you for your answer anyway.
